# Can a numpy array be compared to an integer?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, python-imaging-library

This was in some code that I'll have to use for a homework:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
img = np.array(Image.open("image.png"))[:,:,0]
Known = (img > 0).astype(int)
```

What does the last line - `Known = (img > 0).astype(int)` - do?

(I tried looking it up, but it's hard to search for the ">" symbol in google search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does pretty much what you'd expect: it tests the array `img` to see if it's greater than 0. But since it's a NumPy array, this is an elementwise comparison: *each element* is compared to 0. This creates an array of Booleans with the result of the comparison for each element. `astype(int)` converts this array of Booleans to an array of integers. Basically, it's making a mask of the non-zero pixels in the image.

Comment: If you want to answer 'are all elements in the array less than 10,' you can use numpy.all.

Answer (score 1):

`(img > 0).astype(int)` = 1 if the array cell is bigger than 0 and 0 if not

```py
>>> a=np.array([3,5,3])
>>> (a>0)
array([ True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
>>> (a>0).astype(int)
array([1, 1, 1])
```